# Grammatical analyze with the form "AS TO+V"

Tags: conjunctions, infinitives, prepositional-phrases, as

I am studying English in France and I have to do a grammatical analysis of a phrase that is:

> Ah, what would I not have given to have possessed Gatsby's elaborately monogrammed shirts, not have sacrificed if only I could have been so consumed with wonder at a dream come true **as to have thrown them in flamboyant offering** at the feet of some unattainable girl...

I have to explain the passage in bold. I am so confused with the use of "as to have thrown", I found some explanation about the "AS TO" but never with a verb after it.

Comment: Does it become more clear for you if you add the word "['so' as to](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/so_as_to_do_something)"?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang: if you look at your link, it means "in order to" which does not work in this context. What it actually means is "that I would have".

Comment: @JavaLatte, I agree that "that I would have" is an excellent substitution for the phrase as written. Meanwhile, do you also mean then that do not think the phrase was meant as "so as to"?

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang: The meaning is completely differerent. In "so A as to B", the degree of A is so great that B is inevitable.  In "A so as to B", one does A in order to achieve B.

Comment: The full sentence seems to be: [*Ah, what would I not have given to have possessed Gatsby's elaborately monogrammed shirts, not have sacrificed if only I could have been so consumed with wonder at a dream come true as to have thrown them in flamboyant offering at the feet of some unattainable girl who, realizing the agony of my soul, would then have buried her lovely head in them, sobbing out the rebirth of her love for me!*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=alaaAAAAIAAJ&q=%22then+have+buried+her%22&dq=%22then+have+buried+her%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y)

Comment: I consider myself a reasonably competent native speaker, but even I have trouble parsing that! I'm *guessing* that the entirety of ***if only I could have been so consumed with wonder at a dream come true as to have thrown them in flamboyant offering*** is in fact "parenthetical" (and could thus be discarded while still leaving a valid sentence), but this appears to leave ***sacrificed*** as an intransitive usage, which is somewhat problematic for me. I would expect the "object" of "sacrifice" (Gatsby's shirts) to be explicitly referenced (with a pronoun such as ***them***).

Answer (score 6):

The structure "**so** consumed with wonder...**as** to have thrown them" is analogous to "**so** happy **that** I could...".

so X as to do Y

so X that it does Y

**So ... as** is complemented with a clause whose verb is an infinitive.

**So ... that** is complemented with a clause whose verb is tensed.

> He was so enamored of her that he **threw** his fancy shirts in a pile at
>   her feet and set them on fire.
>
> He was so enamored of her as **to throw** his fancy shirts in a pile at
>   her feet and set them on fire.

The infinitive refers to the idea of the action, nominally. It is not presented as action that takes place or has taken place or took place or had taken place or will take place or will have taken place. In the *that*-clause above, the action took place. In the *as*-clause above, the action is one that *could* take place or could have taken place, because he was so enamored.

**To have thrown** is a present perfect infinitive. The perfect infinitive refers to a completed action in hindsight, often philosophically or ruefully. Again, as an infinitive, the action is seen in the abstract, nominally, not as action that actually took place, though it may have taken place.

> It is better **to have loved** and lost than never **to have loved** at all.
>
> The mountain climber sat in his study, his broken foot propped on a
>   chair. **To have climbed** Mount Everest would be a great
>   accomplishment, he thought. If only he had not broken his foot stumbling on a rock at base camp.
>
> The mountain climber sat in his study, his broken foot propped on a chair. **To have climbed** Mount Everest is a great accomplishment, he thought. If only I had not broken my foot on the return to base camp, I would be climbing K2 now.

Comment: Oh! Ok! How could have I missed it. Thank you a lot, I understand better now.